# Shutting down spring boot application in linux

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am trying to shut down the spring boot app running inside Linux (EC2 instance) using the below command:

`netstat -ano | grep :6060` returns PID which I use in the kill command

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

The spring boot app shut down successfully but restarted automatically after some time without executing the jar. So whenever I try to execute the jar again, I get the "6060 port already in use" error. Again I manually need to kill the new PID before executing my jar.

Comment: Yeah, that is likely the expected and documented behavior.  What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that, but I believe one way is using the `shutdown` actuator endpoint. Its described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints)
Note, it's disabled by default so you should enable it.